Как развернуть Rabbitmq кластер на разных хостах?
Подскажите пожалуйста с помощью чего можно создать Rabbitmq кластер. Задача такова, что для организации отказоустойчивой системы нужно развернуть rabbitmq в docker compose на 3 машинах. Пробовал много способов, но так и не получилось ничего. Может был у кого-то опыт или есть туториал подробный. Буду благодарен.
Как развернуть отдельно на каждой я разобрался. А вот как связать их: где прописать hostname и ip машин, какие параметры в docker compose environment задать - нет.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480115/rabbitmq-cluster-with-docker-on-different-servers
